# jQuery: selector question (dash)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, classname

i'm trying to select objects which are having a dash in their classname - like `$("div.nav-next");`

it doesnt work - seems like the dash is the problems - any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure it works. I have done it for years in both jQuery and CSS. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I will second Bolt's comment. This works as shown: http://jsfiddle.net/VW8WP/ It's possible there is some other markup we're not seeing that is causing issues with your selector.

Comment: I believe it does work...type this into the firebug console to test $(".user-action-time") it is the blue box just above here and you'll see that it returns an object.

Comment: sorry i didn't realize that the elements in questions were generated by a plugin (so not existing in the dom ...) shame on me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Get rid of the "div" portion.

```
$('.nav-next')
```